# Weird key-name with mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

I have a Tab Separated Value file that I need to import in mongodb
I do

```
mongoimport -d mydb -c blsItem --type tsv --file .\BLS_3.01.txt --fieldFile .\fieldnames-bls.txt
```

fieldname-bls.txt contains all the keys nicely separated in an UTF-8 file:

```
blsKey
germanDescription
englishDescription
```

The result of the import is, that every *blsKey* starts with glibberish

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4eee82136e6ffebe9085debd"), "´╗┐blsKey" : "B100000", "germanDescription" : "Vollkornbrote", "englishDescription" : ""
```

But even VIM shows the "fieldname-bls.txt" nice and clean.
What is going on?

Comment: Do you have a BOM at the start of your UTF-8 file? If so, try without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like UTF-8 [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Convert your file into UTF-8 **without** BOM, that's it.